# Execute CMD Command with QProcess and Save it in QString

Tags: c++, qt

I wanted to execute the cmd command `"wmic share get name"` with `QProcess` and then save the result of the command in the `QString` variable. In further, I wanted to show it in `QMessageBox` or ... How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `QProcess` for this. Let's say I want to execute `g++`. Example:

```
    QProcess p;
    p.setProgram("g++");
    p.setArguments({"-O3", "filename.cpp"});
    p.start();

    // wait for the process to finish executing
    // returns true on success
    if (!p.waitForFinished()) {
       qDebug() << "Failed to execute!!";
       const QString error = p.readAllStandardError();
       if (!error.isEmpty()) {
        qDebug () << "Exit status: " << p.exitStatus() << ", Error: " << error;   
       }
        return;
    }

    // read output
    const QString output = p.readAllStandardOutput();
    qDebug () << output;

    // read error
    const QString error = p.readAllStandardError();
    if (!error.isEmpty()) {
        qDebug () << error;   
    }

    //do whatever you want with output
```

Comment: Can you edit it to run the command "wmic share get name". I edit it but it doesn't work.

Comment: What is the output you are getting? Is there any error? I am on linux, so I can't run `wmic`. Note, you may have to give full path: `C:\path\wmic.exe` or something

Comment: I get nothing. I don't know where is the problem.

Comment: Have you tried running through debugger? Try again, I made a little change at `if (!p.waitForFinished()) {`. It will give you some results

Comment: It works now, but there is another problem. In the output, I have got a lot of \r\r\r and \n delimiter. How can I remove these things from the output in the console?

Comment: Just use `QString::trimmed()` method. `output = output.trimmed()`